# Using Log4Net.ErrorFormat how can I log the stacktrace?

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to use ErrorFormat method because it is easer to read, safer and faster.
But I also want to log the exception stacktrace.

I tried `log.ErrorFormat("My {0} message", "pretty", exception);`

But it only logs "My pretty message"
Is it possible to use Error/Debug/Info Format in such way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
log.ErrorFormat("My {0} message: {1}", "pretty", exception);
```

Comment: Although it's worth noting that this formats the exception into the log message, so for example if you use Log4Net's PatternLayout's `stackTrace`  or `exception` placeholders they won't contain anything.